# Ferramenta de cadastro

Tags: asp.net, asp

Possuo uma aplicação com cerca de 30 cadastros básicos, atualmente utilizo uma ferramenta em .asp na qual, configuro trabalhando com `Request` tenho uma página só genérica atuando em todos os cadastros.

Atualmente está cada vez mais difícil ter acesso a publicação de nova versão no cliente, então gostaria de uma indicação de alguma ferramenta de cadastro que possa ser configurada via banco de dados.

Minha aplicação (`VB`) possuí páginas `.asp`e `.aspx`. Se a solução for em `C#`, posso converter ou dar um jeito de trabalhar em paralelo.

Comment: Se eu entendi, você tem uma única página que responde à vários formulários. É isso mesmo?

Comment: De forma básica, é isso sim.

Comment: Acho que você deveria detalhar mais a sua intenção, dando exemplos do que você tem atualmente e se possível de como gostaria de fosse.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que está acontecendo, tem como explicar mais?

Comment: Bom, o fato da manutenção ficar já onerosa é justamente por isso - ela tenta atender qualquer página. E isso não é uma boa prática. Não tenho como dar uma resposta simples para te solucionar. Mas pesquisa por `ViewModels`, certamente o conceito poderá ser adaptado e irá deixar sua manutenção mais "suave". E, por fora, recomendo estudar MVC como tecnologia e DDD como pattern de arquitetura.